# Update Query with INNER JOIN between tables in 2 different databases on 1 server

Tags: sql-server, database, syntax, inner-join

Need some SQL syntax help :-)

Both databases are on the same server

```
db1 = DHE
db2 = DHE_Import

UPDATE DHE.dbo.tblAccounts 
INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink 
    ON DHE.dbo.tblAccounts.AccountCode = DHE_Import.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink.AccountCode 
SET DHE.dbo.tblAccounts.ControllingSalesRep = DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink.SalesRepCode
```

I can do a query in Access with linked tables with similar syntax - BUT SQL doesn't like it.

I'm sure it's a simple issue :-D

Thanks!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You could call it just style, but I prefer aliasing to improve readability.

```
UPDATE A    
  SET ControllingSalesRep = RA.SalesRepCode   
from DHE.dbo.tblAccounts A
  INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink RA
    ON A.AccountCode = RA.AccountCode
```

For MySQL

```
UPDATE DHE.dbo.tblAccounts A 
  INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink RA 
      ON A.AccountCode = RA.AccountCode 
SET A.ControllingSalesRep = RA.SalesRepCode
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on MySQL. The correct syntax there would be `UPDATE DHE.dbo.tblAccounts A INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink RA ON A.AccountCode = RA.AccountCode SET ControllingSalesRep = RA.SalesRepCode`.

Comment: That's right... the answer above (proposed by @jerry) does not work for mysql.

Comment: personally I don't like using aliasing unless it is necessary, like when there are lots of fields or tables involved, etc. But then I do still qualify each field with tablename.fieldname for clarity even without aliasing

Answer (score 35):

Following is the  MySQL syntax:

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field2
SET table1.field3 = table2.field4 
WHERE ...... ;
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/faizanahmad/archive/2009/01/05/join-in-sql-update--statement.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Sorry its late, but I guess it would be of help to those who land here finding a solution to similar problem. 
The set clause should come right after the update clause. So rearranging your query with a bit change does the work.

```
UPDATE DHE.dbo.tblAccounts 
SET DHE.dbo.tblAccounts.ControllingSalesRep
    = DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink.SalesRepCode
from DHE.dbo.tblAccounts 
INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink 
    ON DHE.dbo.tblAccounts.AccountCode
        = DHE_Import.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink.AccountCode
```

Answer (score 5):

Should look like this:

```
UPDATE DHE.dbo.tblAccounts
   SET DHE.dbo.tblAccounts.ControllingSalesRep = 
       DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink.SalesRepCode
  from DHE.dbo.tblAccounts 
     INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink 
        ON DHE.dbo.tblAccounts.AccountCode =
           DHE_Import.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink.AccountCode
```

Update table is repeated in FROM clause.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE table1 a
 inner join  table2 b on (a.kol1=a.b.kol1...)
SET a.kol1=b.kol1
WHERE 
a.kol1='' ...
```

for me until the syntax worked -MySQL

Answer (score 1):

which may be useful

```
Update
    A INNER JOIN B ON A.COL1=B.COL3
SET
    A.COL2='CHANGED', A.COL4=B.COL4,......
WHERE ....;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to update using Inner join query in SQL .You can do it **without** *using* `FROM` clause. Here is an example :

```
    UPDATE customer_table c 

      INNER JOIN  
          employee_table e
          ON (c.city_id = e.city_id)  

    SET c.active = "Yes"

    WHERE c.city = "New york";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is explained here http://erabhinavrana.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-execute-update-query-by-applying.html

It also has other useful code snippets which are commonly used.

```
update <dbname of 1st table>.<table name of 1st table> A INNER JOIN <dbname of 2nd table>.<table name of 2nd table> RA ON A.<field name of table 1>=RA.<field name of table 2> SET A.<field name of table 1 to be updated>=RA.<field name of table 2 to set value in table 1>
```

Replace data in `<>` with your appropriate values.

That's It.
**source:**

> http://www.dynamic-coders.com/how-to-update-two-different-tables-in-different-databases-on-same-server

Comment: You should paste a summary of the provided link in your post to prevent deadlinking

Answer (score 0):

```
//For Access Database:
UPDATE ((tblEmployee
LEFT JOIN tblCity ON (tblEmployee.CityCode = tblCity.CityCode))
LEFT JOIN tblCountry ON (tblEmployee.CountryCode = tblCountryCode))
SET tblEmployee.CityName = tblCity.CityName, 
tblEmployee.CountryName = tblCountry.CountryName
WHERE (tblEmployee.CityName = '' OR tblEmployee.CountryName = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update one table using Inner Join

  UPDATE Table1 SET name=ml.name
FROM table1 t inner JOIN
Table2 ml ON t.ID= ml.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly for me.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.col1 = b.col2 SET a.col_which_you_want_update = b.col_from_which_you_update;
```