# Update Database Column field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to databases and I'm trying to run an update query whose pseudo code looks like the following:
    Update the last entry of TableA.ColumnA using the value in the last entry of TableB.ColumnB

I tried to do the following code:

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET TableA.ColumnA = (Select Last (ColumnB) from TableB )
    WHERE (((TableA.ColumnA)=(Select LAST(ColumnA) from TableA)));
```

But I get an error from Access that says "operation must use an updateable query".

I would appreciate any guidance or help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MAX` function

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET TableA.ColumnA = (Select MAX(ColumnB) from TableB )
    WHERE TableA.ColumnA = (Select MAX(ColumnA) from TableA);
```

Comment: It gives me the same message.
I tried to change the (Select MAX(ColumnB) from TableB ) for any number and it works but not when using the select query.

Comment: Thank you for your help first of all.

So if I try this
    UPDATE TableA
        SET TableA.ColumnA = 4
        WHERE TableA.ColumnA = (Select MAX(ColumnA) from TableA);
it will work or if I use my original attempt

UPDATE TableA
    SET TableA.ColumnA = 4
    WHERE (((TableA.ColumnA)=(Select LAST(ColumnA) from TableA)));
It works but not when using the select query

Comment: Did you try to change the permission of the folder?

Comment: No I have no idea how to do that. I'm a college student. Do you mean open the database as exclusive?

Comment: You can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789709/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error-in-ms-access). Maybe it can give you some idea