# “Operation must use an updateable query” error in MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

This question has been asked many times, my case seems to be the simplest, still I did not find the answer to my question...

The environment is Windows, Access 2013.
Table tbl_rap is linked, resides on MS SQL Server 2007

Table tbl_rap is constructed as follows:

```
id - int (Identity)
field_1 nchar(10)
field_2 nchar(1)
```

The following code works

```
sql_cmd = "INSERT INTO tbl_rap (field_1,field_2) VALUES ('010308HB3','R')"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql_cmd
```

But this code

```
sql_cmd = "UPDATE tbl_rap SET field_2 = 'X' WHERE field_1 = '010308HB3'"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql_cmd
```

fails with run-time error 3037 "Operation must use an updateable query"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very much like [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789709/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error-in-ms-access), but only one of the answers looks appropriate to me. Try `UPDATE DISTINCTROW` instead of just `UPDATE`.

Comment: I tried before I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

As you use nchar(10), you must pass a string of 10 characters, say:

```
sql_cmd = "UPDATE tbl_rap SET field_2 = 'X' WHERE field_1 = '010308HB3 '"
```

Comment: I changed the code as recommended, unfortunately the problem persists...

Comment: It was just an example. Clearly, the search text doesn't match the actual field text, so double-check the field content.

Comment: If the UPDATE could not find a matching record in the table, it would fail differently.

Comment: Then you probably miss a _timestamp_ field in the table and to relink the table after having added this.

Comment: How did you arrive at the notion that a timestamp field is needed?

Comment: Because that is often the reason for a table being non updatable.