# How can I use Join On for update data on sql php?

Tags: php, sql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 named: Users

Rows:

- Name_Users
- Age
- Data
- Email

Table 2 named: Data

Rows:

- Name_Data
- Data1
- Data2
- Data3

I need UPDATE the row Data on Users with the Data3 of table Data when on table Data the row Data1 = YES To the username with the Data1 = Yes.

I have this:

```
UPDATE Users JOIN Data ON Data1 = 'Yes' SET Data = Data3 WHERE Name_Data = Name_Users
```

I try others but nothing work, Is possible do it?, thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That syntax is product specific.)

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894353/update-query-with-inner-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases-on-1-server

Comment: @jarlh Im using php my admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you sql will be like below

```
   UPDATE Users u
   JOIN Data d ON d.Name_Data = u.Name_Users and d.Data1 = 'Yes' 
   SET u.Data = d.Data3
```